# Jacoco. Compute coverage information for each test case in a test suite

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

Right now I use Jacoco to know the coverage of the whole test suite, but I would need to break down the coverage information by test case.

I need to create a program that does this since we need to automate a large suite. I guess this should be done by using the API...

Is there a way of doing this? I'm new to Jacoco, please help.

Comment: Hi, Did you did you find an option. Even I wanted the same

Comment: I had to create a surefire provider to do so: https://github.com/marcelinorc/junco-provider. Please let me know if you find it useful and report any bugs. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks,  I am with TestNG. But this is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

The TestNG plug in for Eclipse allows you to select and run an individual test case. You can then inspect the result of running that particular test case.

However, there does not seem to be a way to, for instance, click on a single line of code and query what test cases visited that line.

What other use cases did you have in mind?

Comment: Thank you @Bob Dalgleish. I have updated my question to be more clear. I need it to create a program that does it. I'll see if the TestNG plugin code is available and i'll take a look at it. I upvoted your answer anyway. Thanks again.